# Where are the plugins in netbeans 9 incubation RC1?

Tags: apache, netbeans, plugins, netbeans-9

I can not access to the plugins in the netbeans 9 incubation (Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708).

It looks like if there was delete the plugins repository from plugins update center.

There are only few plugins but I need some that they are not there, and I have some problems because they have some dependencies with others.

Do we have to keep waiting until the stable version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to setup apache tomcat in Netbeans 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51807109/2985643).

Comment: I think that it is different because I'm focusing on the plugins problem instead of only the installation of server, but the solution it seems the same. I hope this will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache NetBeans (incubating) 9.0 consists basically of java se. In the meantime, the second donation has been completed, The modules for features providing support for JavaScript, PHP, Groovy, and enterprise Java (i.e., Java EE or, as it is known now, Jakarta EE features wil be integrated in near future.

**Solution:**
These features that are not integrated into Apache NetBeans (incubating) 9.0 yet, but they can be used by manually adding NetBeans IDE 8.2 update center.

> **Tools | Plugins** in Apache NetBeans (incubating) 9.0 and, in the Settings tab, register the NetBeans IDE 8.2 update center:
>
> http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz

More info at [Apache incubation](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-happened-to-my)